# Consume RESTFul web service with Xamarin.Forms just like in POSTMAN

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin, and facing a problem while consuming RESTful web service in my application.

We are using encryption technologies while calling web services. I need to implement those scenarios in my Xamarin.Forms app too. For that purpose I have added an existing Encryption method (which we are using in native Android, and web applications) as a .NET assembly to my project.

My problem is that, I am not getting the same result as POSTMAN in my Xamarin.Forms, so that I couldn't decrypt the result from the web service. When I am trying to decrypt it shows an error.

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

The result from POSTMAN is able to decrypt by using the same decryption technologies.

**I am using below code in application.**

```
public static string API_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.2.126:86/Appointment.svc/";
    public static async Task<WebResult> doLogin(string phone, string password)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(API_BASE_URL + "PatientRegistration");
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest
        {
            phonenumber = phone,
            password = password,
            device_id = "asdfsf",
            GCM_Code = "esfdsdf"
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest);
        EncryptionClass encryptionMethod = new EncryptionClass();
        bool mOut = false;
        string encryptedData = encryptionMethod.Encryption(json, out mOut);
        if (mOut)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(encryptedData, Encoding.UTF8);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                bool dOut = false;
                string dcryptrdData = encryptionMethod.Decryption(result, out dOut);
                if (dOut)
                {
                    WebResult webApiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebResult>(dcryptrdData);
                    return webApiResult;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**Below I am attaching the screenshot of POSTMAN client.**
[image]
Since I am new to Xamarin platform(This is my first attempt) I doubt that I am doing something wrong in my application part, otherwise I should get the same result as POSTMAN. Please help me to figure out the issue.

**UPDATE**

I have tested the result that i got via POSTMAN in my application's decryption method, and its working fine. So I am assuming the problem is with in my applications code.Please help me out of this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seeing the error that you posted and the values shown in your screenshot, you're expecting a base64 value somewhere while decoding, and the values in your screenshots are not base64. So, it seems something goes wrong while decoding.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis in POSTMAN everything is fine and we were checked that.

Comment: But postman does not run the same code as your decoding mechanism in your app

Comment: let me check that, i will put the response which i get from postman to my app and let u know.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis you are right, there is an error, but its different, `Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string`

Comment: The message is different, but the idea remains the same; it expects a base64 string and the values you are showing are not base64. I don't know what your code should do, but either the resulting value from the call is incorrect, or the handling of the value is incorrect

Comment: Thanks for the comments friend, between, is my web service calling part is correct?

Comment: From the error message you receive I gather that it receives some kind of value, it's just not the correct format. Your call seems to be succeeding. Of course, I do not know your requirements so there is no way of saying that with a 100% certainty.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Update: The postman result is working in my application's decryption method, before I was using the `raw` value, when I change it to `pretty>json` the result is working.